# Why am I having a gap if I try to write code in beautiful manner?

Tags: html, css

```css
pl {
    white-space: pre-line;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Creating Gap</h2>
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
 <pl>
    (a) This is line number One
    (b) This is line number Two
</pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>

<br>

<h2>This one is fine</h2>
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
 <pl>(a) This is line number One
    (b) This is line number Two</pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>
```

I am having a very weird issue if I write a code like this

```
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
 <pl>
    (a) This is line number One
    (b) This is line number Two
</pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>
```

It creates a gap between the first and the other lines. (You can see in the snippet)

but when if
I write a code like this

```
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
    <pl>(a) This is line number One
    (b) This is line number Two</pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>
```

It removed the Gap. 
I want to write a code in beautiful manners. So plz help me to remove the gap if I write like this

```
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
 <pl>
    (a) This is line number One
    (b) This is line number Two
</pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>
```

Here is the CSS

```
pl {
    white-space: pre-line;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: there is no HTMl tag called <pl> do you want to create a new paragra[h <p> or an ordered list <ol>

Comment: I was trying to create my own for some specific reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just took a look at CSS Documentation on `white-space: pre-line;`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). The documentation states:

> `pre-line`
>
> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

This means that the `pre-line` property will collapse multiple consecutive whitespaces into one, and lines are broken according to newlines put in source code by the developer. Therefore, you should do this instead:

```css
pl {
  /* Removed the whitespace property */
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Creating Gap</h2>
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
 <pl>
    (a) This is line number One <br> <!-- You'll have to add this br tag if you want to make your code look as stated -->
    (b) This is line number Two
 </pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>

<br>

<h2>This one is fine</h2>
<p>
  Why there is a gap below?
 <pl>(a) This is line number One <br>
    (b) This is line number Two</pl>
'I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. I don't know. '
</p>
```

Comment: Oh Ok Thanks user11350388